# Регулярное выражение. Вырезать строки между пробелами

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

У меня вопрос по регулярному выражению.

Есть тексты (ниже) и из него мне нужно вырезать 3 и 4 по счету строки.

```
'SFX N1 0 0 . +Sg+Nom #',
'SFX N1 0 ны . +Sg+Gen #',
'SFX N1 лар ның . +Sg+Acc #',
```

Чтобы в итоге было

```
'0', '0'
'0', 'ны'
лар', 'ның'
```

Comment: В данном случае проще воспользоваться функцией `explode( разделитель, строка )`

Comment: Спасибо вам! Воспользовался вашим советом

Comment: Не надо писать в названии "Решено". Надо дать ответ на свой же вопрос и потом принять этот ответ, жмакнув по зеленой галке.

Comment: @u_mulder а вашим советом не воспользуется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользовался функцией explode() в PHP

```
$str = 'SFX N1 лар ның . +Sg+Acc #';

$str_explode = explode(" ", $str);
echo $str_explode[2]; // лар 
echo $str_explode[3]; // ның
```